# What format do the most browsers support?

Tags: html

I uploaded a mp3 audio to my website, because of its format some browsers or Operating Systems do not support it, what format do the most browser support so I convert my audio to that?

Comment: This is really, really easy to find out with a search in any competent search engine.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what you are doing? Is this file being posted for download by users? Is it being streamed? Is it embedded into the page as background music of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`w3schools`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp), here is a chart which shows which browsers support each file:

```
Browser                     MP3      Wav       Ogg

Internet Explorer 9+        YES      NO        NO
Chrome 6+                   YES      YES       YES
Firefox 3.6+                NO       YES       YES
Safari 5+                   YES      YES       NO
Opera 10+                   NO       YES       YES
```